# Mac OS 10.8.4 and Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, osx-mountain-lion, microsoft-excel-2011

I am trying to delete everything after the "," on each cell in a column of email addresses. For example:

```
jonsmith@hotmail.com,2013-08-06 13:27:53,bounced
sallyfield@google.com,2013-02-06 13:05:47,bounced
susanmiller@aol.com,2013-02-01 04:21:28,bounced
```

I have over 1000 records.  Is there a way to do this without deleting part of each cell individually? Is there a macro that would do this for me?

Answer (score 1):

Select the column with the data.

Depending on your version of Excel, go to the "Data" menu (Excel 2008 and before) or the "Data" Ribbon tab (Excel 2011) and select ["Text to Columns"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214261).

Select "Delimited" and use "," as the separator. Click "Finish" and only the e-mail addresses should be left in column A. Feel free to delete the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

In another column place this function `=LEFT(A1, SEARCH(",",A1)-1)`, you can then copy the function down for all of the other columns.

This will make the B column the data that is left of the comma in the A column.

Comment: I'm a complete novice at this. If I have 1570 records and want this to happen for each record, what would the formula look like?

Comment: the answer @JoshR provided you just need to drag down in the adjacent column and excel will adjust for each of the 1570 records

Comment: If you have the formula input to cell B1 for instance, select that cell and there will be a little black square in the bottom-right of the cell. Double-click that square and it will copy the formula down all of the cells in the B column.